# How to make a NSURLSesssion GET request with cookies

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm using the Pinterest SDK to download a Pinterest Pin's link, (sample link that I get back from the server:  https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/186195765822871832/4801566892554728205/77314e40aeb26c0dc412e9cfa82f8dccc401fdb2b9806a3fe17ba8bafdb50510).

About 5 days ago I started getting 404 errors in my NSURLSesssion when trying to access similar links that I'd pulled down from Pinterest.

A friend said that he believes Pinterest must now require cookies to access that link.

How can I configure my session so that I can use cookies and get a 200 response back from Pinterest?

UPDATED CODE:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


var url = URL(string: "https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/186195765822871832/4801566892554728205/77314e40aeb26c0dc412e9cfa82f8dccc401fdb2b9806a3fe17ba8bafdb50510")

var getSourceURLFromPinterest: URLSessionDataTask? = nil
let sessionConfig: URLSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30.0

let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
let cookieHeaderField = ["Set-Cookie": "key=value, key2=value2"]
let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: cookieHeaderField, for: url!)
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: url, mainDocumentURL: url)

let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
getSourceURLFromPinterest = session.dataTask(with: url! as URL) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
        print("error is \(error)")
    }
    if response == nil {
    print("no response")

    } else if let _ = data {

        //Config Request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(
            url: (response?.url)!,
            cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
            timeoutInterval: 30.0)
        request.httpMethod = "HEAD"

        var statusCode = Int()
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let checkURLForResponse = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {urlData, myResponse, responseError in
            if let httpResponse = myResponse as? HTTPURLResponse {
                 statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                               switch statusCode {
                case  _ where statusCode < 500 && statusCode > 299 && statusCode != 405: //whitelisted 405 to exclude Amazon.com false errors
                    print("status code \(statusCode) for \(url)")
                default:
                    break;
                }
            } else {  print("***NO httpResponse for \(url)") }
        }
        checkURLForResponse.resume()
    }
}
 getSourceURLFromPinterest!.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers may work generally, but specifically for me this is how I coded the request in order to get a response from Pinterest's server.  Note that specifically what I am doing I think is related to a possible bug in Pinterest's server, see: https://github.com/pinterest/ios-pdk/issues/124

I commented out my personal Pinterest session ID

```
var cookieSession = String()
var cookieCSRFToken = String()

var myWebServiceUrl = URL(string: "https://www.pinterest.com/r/pin/186195765821344905/4801566892554728205/a9bb098fcbd6b73c4f38a127caca17491dafc57135e9bbf6a0fdd61eab4ba885")

let requestOne = URLRequest(url: myWebServiceUrl!)
let sessionOne = URLSession.shared

let taskOne = sessionOne.dataTask(with: requestOne, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
    else {
        print("RESPONSE: \(response)")

        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("DATA: " + dataString)
        } // end: if

        var cookies:[HTTPCookie] = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies! as [HTTPCookie]
        print("Cookies Count = \(cookies.count)")
        for cookie:HTTPCookie in cookies as [HTTPCookie] {

            // Get the _pinterest_sess ID
            if cookie.name as String == "_pinterest_sess" {
                //var cookieValue : String = "CookieName=" + cookie.value as String
                cookieSession = cookie.value as String
                print(cookieSession)
            }

            // Get the csrftoken
            if cookie.name as String == "csrftoken" {
                cookieCSRFToken = cookie.value
                print(cookieCSRFToken)
            }
        } // end: for

    } // end: if
})
taskOne.resume()

var requestTwo = URLRequest(url: myWebServiceUrl!)

cookieSession = "XXXXXXXX"

cookieCSRFToken = "JHDylCCKKNToE4VXgofq1ad3hg06uKKl"

var cookieRequest = "_auth=1; _b=\"AR4XTkMmqo9JKradOZyuMoSWcMdsBMuBHHIM21wj2RPInwdkbl2yuy56yQR4iqxJ+N4=\"; _pinterest_pfob=disabled; _pinterest_sess=\"" + cookieSession + "\"; csrftoken=" + cookieCSRFToken as String


requestTwo.setValue(cookieRequest as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Cookie")


let taskTwo = sessionOne.dataTask(with: requestTwo, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
    else {
        print("RESPONSE: \(response)")

    } // end: if
})
taskTwo.resume()

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a cookie based session in the following way. Please let me know if you need any help. The below is just an example

```
    let session: URLSession = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: myUrlRequest { urlData, response, responseError in

        let httpRes: HTTPURLResponse = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)!
        let cookies:[HTTPCookie] = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: httpRes.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: httpRes.url!)
        HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: response?.url!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
        if responseError == nil {

        }else {

        }
    }.resume()
```

Feel free to suggest edits to make it better. Please let me know if the below doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks I added that, but in my playground cookies looks like it's an empty array?

Comment: I get it, but what if I want to set JSESSIONID inside a cookie *before* runnung that dataTask?

Answer (score 0):

When you do an authentication with the server, the server gives out the cookies, which you receives in the header of the response. You can extract that and set as a cookie in the shared storage of cookies. So everytime you make a call, for those domain, the cookies will be shared and checked, and if valid, it will let you in.

```
let resp: HTTPURLResponse = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)!
    let cookies:[HTTPCookie] = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: resp.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: resp.url!)
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookies(cookies, for: response?.url!, mainDocumentURL: nil)
```

In this, the `cookies` will be an array, which contain cookies in an array. An response may contain more than one cookies.

In case, if you are using third party framework to manage the HTTP requests like `Alamofire` then it will take cares of the cookie management itself.

Comment: Thanks but in the playground my cookie array is empty